# iOS - Xcode inaction -> action button not "doing" defined action

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, controller

My add new "to do" not dismissing view and returning to main VC

- Using Xcode 10.3 using Swift 5
- I'm following a video tutorial using Swift 4 
  YouTube series -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y4uwTdivl64&list=PLP8n25bNfkdc4Vopq3lMi_iVsMdqXYGVj&index=6&frags=wn
- I've coded as they instruct, but the "add new to do" isn't passing the contents of the textField to the mainVC and dismissing the current (toDoVC).
- no errors in the debug log view

  '''

// main VC//

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        textView.text = ""

        for currentToDo in toDoController.toDosArray {
            textView.text = "\(String(describing: textView.text)))\n\(currentToDo)"
        }
    }
}
```

//secondary VC (adding to do)//

```
import UIKit

class toDoViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!


    @IBAction func saveToDo(_ sender: Any) {
        toDoController.addToDo(newToDo: textField.text!)
        print(self.textField!) //debug line
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

//controller//

```
import UIKit

class toDoController: NSObject {
    class func addToDo( newToDo:String){
        toDoController.toDosArray.append( newToDo)
    }

    class func removeToDo( atIndex:Int ) {
        toDoController.toDosArray.remove(at: atIndex)
    }
} 
   <br/>
'''
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Try change "class toDoController" to "extension", and remove "NSObject". And rename "class func" to "func"
Change `"\(String(describing: textView.text)))\n\(currentToDo)"` to `"\(String(describing: textView.text))\n\(currentToDo)"`
Don't use force wrap, when You don't must.
Try use
`if let text = textField.text {toDoController.addToDo(newToDo: text)} else {return}`

Comment: And You remove ": NSObject"?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.

When I drop the paren I get an SIGABRT when it runs (after a successful build)

When I drop "class" from the toDoController and replace it with extension (which hasn't yet be taught) i get this error:

"Use of undeclared type 'toDoController"

Since toDoController isn't yet defined, how can I extend it? The controller code above in my initial post is the first instance of the toDoController.

Comment: Yes I removed that...still got errors.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I don't recognize that You have `toDoController` and 'toDoViewController' not one name. 
Try  `toDoController().addToDo(newToDo: textField.text!)`. Rember about (). And better don't use force wrap, how i mention before. 
If this work, better way is make variable `let toDoController = toDoController()`

Comment: @JamesVoo thank you for your help. since I am new to programming in Swift, I'm going to start the lesson over and see if I did something (order of operations or tied an action/outlet to the wrong override action that is causing these issues.

Comment: Good luck with your further learning :)

Comment: Are you sure that the method viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) in ViewController is being called when you expect it to be? That method does not necessarily get called  when you dismiss another view controller (it depends on what mode the dismissed view controller was presented with). Add a print statement inside viewDidAppear to confirm.